# Empty model on Submit method in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

It's stupid, but I have no idea what to do. I have the following class diagram:

Model:

```
 public class TKKService
    {
        public string Name = string.Empty;

        public TKKService() {}
    }
```

Controller:

```
 public class ServiceController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new TKKService());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(TKKService Mod)
        {
            TKKService serv = new TKKService();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                serv.Name = Mod.Name + "_next";
            }
            return View(serv);
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@model TKK_Portal.Models.TKKService

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Model.Name    
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)

    <input type="submit" value="Wyslij"/>
}
```

When doing a `Submit` method, `Model.Name` not contain edited data. It takes the default value `Empty`.

Comment: Have you debugged and checked that `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is returning true?

Comment: ModelState.IsValid returns True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove it from the ModelState if you intend to modify its value in the POST action:

```
ModelState.Remove("Name");
serv.Name = Mod.Name + "_next";
```

The reason this happens stems from the design of the Html helpers (like TextBoxFor, CheckBoxFor, ...). They will first look in the `ModelState` when binding their values and after that in the Model. In your POST action there's already a value in the ModelState (the one that was initially submitted), so that's the value being used.

Also make sure that Name is a property and not a field:

```
public class TKKService
{
    public TKKService() 
    {
        this.Name = string.Empty;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The reason for this is because the model binder is working with properties (that have public setter) and not with fields.

Comment: The problem actually lay in the lack of getters and setters. Thank you :)

Comment: And in the lack of calling `ModelState.Remove("Name")`.

Answer (score 3):

Define the `Name` as property (even auto-property, if you need) instead.